# how to pares search api odata json result in C#

Tags: 2013, json, odata, search-query

i'm using that search query

```
  string siteUrl = "<site>";
  string  queryText ="Path:\"pathTosearch/*\" IsDocument:1";
  string rowlimit = "10";
  string sortExpression = "Write:descending";
  string uriTempale = "{0}_api/search/query?querytext='{1}'&rowlimit={2}&sortlist='{3}'";
```

and i call it with httpwebrequest i need to parse the result to C# object, is there a direct way to achieve that or i have to use
`dynamic dynObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);`